# Download indivual PST from Office365 Exchange?

Tags: powershell, gmail, exchange, google-workspace, office365

I am migrating my company’s email from Office365 to GoogleApps.

While GoogleApps has an online migration service for email, it doesn’t for Calendar and Contacts. I know that I can go to each individual machine, download the Calendar and Contacts into a PST, and then use GAMME (Googles Importer) to upload into GoogleApps for each user.

What I would like to do is download each individual users Calendar and Contact from Office365 Exchange, via PowerShell or the web Portal or some other method I haven’t thought of, then possibly spinning up a VM and GAMME as each individual person so I can upload. There are only 40 users so it isn’t a big deal to do it manually.

Any thoughts on how to download Calendar and Contacts for each user and download as a PST or CSV?

Though, if anyone else has a solution then that would be great!

Comment: You can't export PST's via PowerShell or via OWA for O365. - You could add the accounts to your Outlook and export PST's from there, this at least saves time going to each machine.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using GAMME profile migration for O365 to Google Apps. You may come into some calendar issues.. also a flag issue that makes all mail in users O365 mailbox turn into drafts.

I would also recommend cloud solutions CMT Tool - that can handle this for you - VM + mig tool.

If you would like to go manual route.. Some change instructions on how to download Calendar and contacts via Export and import would probably be best.

Migration also handles google fanout better then client side upload.

Thanks